# C# - Additional information: Out of memory

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,
 Estou com o seguinte erro na minha solução não sei como resolver agradeço a quem puder me da uma mão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void btnSeleciona_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.Title = "Selecione a foto";
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.Filter = "GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.FileName = "";
        SelecionaOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        txtNomeImagem.Text = SelecionaOpenFileDialog.FileName;            
        if (txtNomeImagem.Text != "")
        {                
            this.FotoPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(txtNomeImagem.Text);               
        }
        else FotoPictureBox.Image = null;
    }
```

o erro está acontencendo na seguinte linha:

```
this.FotoPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(txtNomeImagem.Text);
```

Obrigado

Comment: Esse erro ocorre principalmente quando o formato da imagem selecionado não é válido. Sabe qual o formato a ser selecionado?

Comment: Problemas de gestão de memória variam muito, você sabe o tamanho da imagem que esta tentando alocar? é 32 bits? Qual o formato do arquivo?

Comment: realmente era o formato da imagem agora consegui solucionar graças a voces que me deram a luz haha uma simples besteira gera grande problemas... enfim agradeço pessoal pela ajuda!